# Can anyone describe to me what is the difference between Material and MaterialApp in the flutter, and which to use when?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, frameworks, widget

I'm a newbie at flutter, so, I'm really struggling to understand the difference between these two terms. In flutter documentation the description for these two terms is vague. So could you please provide a clear concept about these two terms?

Answer (score 0):

**`MaterialApp`**

> An application that uses material design.
>
> A convenience widget that wraps a number of widgets that are commonly
> required for material design applications. It builds upon a WidgetsApp
> by adding material-design specific functionality, such as
> AnimatedTheme and GridPaper.
>
> The MaterialApp configures the top-level Navigator to search for
> routes in the following order:
>
> - For the / route, the home property, if non-null, is used.
> - Otherwise, the routes table is used, if it has an entry for the    route.
> - Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called, if provided. It should return a    non-null value for any valid route not handled by home and
>   routes.
> - Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.

[Read more](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html)

**`Material`**

> A piece of material.
>
> The Material widget is responsible for:
>
> ```
> Clipping: If clipBehavior is not Clip.none, Material clips its widget sub-tree to the shape specified by shape, type, and
> ```
>
> borderRadius. By default, clipBehavior is Clip.none for performance
> considerations.
> Elevation: Material elevates its widget sub-tree on the Z axis by elevation pixels, and draws the appropriate shadow.
> Ink effects: Material shows ink effects implemented by InkFeatures like InkSplash and InkHighlight below its children.
>
> The Material Metaphor
>
> Material is the central metaphor in material design. Each piece of
> material exists at a given elevation, which influences how that piece
> of material visually relates to other pieces of material and how that
> material casts shadows.

[Read more](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Material** is a widget or Package used to define a UI element respecting Material rules.
It defines what elevation is, shape, and stuff. using this you can create your app

The material provides different types of property to customize your app.such as

1. Scaffold
2. Text
3. GestureDetector
4. Different types of Buttons
5. Dialogs, alerts, and panels
6. TextField and many more

[Refer official doc for more info](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html)

**MaterialApp** A convenience widget that wraps a number of widgets that are commonly required for material design applications.
It builds upon a WidgetsApp by adding material-design specific functionality, such as AnimatedTheme and GridPaper.

MaterialApp provides different types of property to customize your app.such as

1. Theme -to customize your colors and fonts
2. Routes -to set navigation to redirect to different screens
3. dark theme -to set dark mode and many more

[Refer official doc for more info](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/material)